# I want a regex to Start with but not end with a specific string for Autoit

Tags: regex

There are lots of examples out there but none worked as I want to match specific string not any character. Here is my example.

```
United.Book 
United.Services.Cloud 
United.Services.Sky 
United.Services.Something- Copy  
United.Services.Bolt
```

So I want a regex which will match only 2 and 3rd and 4th (should be United.Services* but should not end with copy). Have tried few but nothing worked

`^United.S.*[^copy]$`

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/Wxi7xi/2).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're not providing more specific limitations, here is the regexp that would match the requirement

> should be United.Services* but should not end with copy

```
United\.Services(?!.*Copy$).*$
```

Here is the test: https://regex101.com/r/9WTngz/1

Answer (score -1):

```
/^United.S.*[^copy$]/i
```

this regex matches the string all the way to the string copy. I added the `i` because the `c` in `copy` is uppercase you can omit it if you want to preserve case sensitivity